# Why i throw System.DllNotFoundException on running Gtk# application on Linux(WSL)?

Tags: c#, linux, gtk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gtk#

i working on Windows and using GtkSharp Library for compile. I created Hello world application and compile it for Windows and Ubuntu. On Windows application working, but on Linux i have exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gtk.Application' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Gtk: libgtk-3-0.dll, libgtk-3.so.0, libgtk-3.0.dylib, gtk-3.dll
   at GLibrary.Load(Library library)
   at Gtk.Application..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Gtk.Application.Init()
   at GtkSharp_Application2.Program.Main(String[] args) in I:\Проекты\Programs\GtkSharp Application2\GtkSharp Application2\Program.cs:line 9
Aborted
```

I don't know why it throws, because i have in builded application all library files

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   306176 Apr 25  2022  AtkSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   120832 Apr 25  2022  CairoSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   259072 Apr 25  2022  GLibSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   610304 Apr 25  2022  GdkSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy  1005568 Apr 25  2022  GioSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   142840 Dec 31 12:59 'GtkSharp Application2'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy    32650 Dec 31 12:59 'GtkSharp Application2.deps.json'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy     5120 Dec 31 12:59 'GtkSharp Application2.dll'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy    10500 Dec 31 12:59 'GtkSharp Application2.pdb'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy      179 Dec 31 12:59 'GtkSharp Application2.runtimeconfig.json'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy  3370496 Apr 25  2022  GtkSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   841872 Oct 23 21:15  Microsoft.CSharp.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy  1232520 Oct 23 21:15  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy    18048 Oct 23 20:52  Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy    24704 Oct 23 21:15  Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy    59008 Oct 23 21:15  Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lisoveliy lisoveliy   203776 Apr 25  2022  PangoSharp.dll
```

I using WSL, but i think problem not caused by this.

I expecting run application by Linux, but that don't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by installing gtk package
`sudo apt install libgtk-3-0`